# How to save and restore session data across logout/relogin in Django?

Tags: django

I'm building a learning website that stores various data about the user's progress.  Currently, I'm using sessions to do this. I want the following behaviour:

1. Unregistered users can return to the site at a later date and the site will remember their progress.
2. When a user creates an account, they will not lose any data about progress already collected.
3. When a registered user logs out, their progress should be hidden.
4. When a registered user logs back in, their progress should be restored.

Sessions work great for behaviors 1-3, but on step 4 the progress fails to be restored.  If I understand how Django handles sessions correctly, all of the session data is destroyed when the user logs out.  What would be the best way to save this data and restore it again when the user logs back in?

Comment: I think you have no other choice but to save the data in the database before the user logs out, and retrieve it back upon login of the same user

Comment: create guest users, such as guest1, guest2, guestN

Comment: @GabrielAmram - That would solve the problem as stated, but could be unreliable in some cases. If a user didn't bother to log out, their session data would never be backed up.  Then that data would not be available if they tried to log in on another computer, or they could lose it altogether if they deleted their cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's no best one way to do this, but the solution I came up with works well so I thought I would share it.

I created a separate table for storing key/value pairs permanently for registered users.  Ideally, you might want to store the data as serialized JSON similar to how the django_sesssion table works, but simple character fields will also work:

```
class account_data(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("username", "key")
```

Each time I want to save or retrieve a key value pair, I check if the user is logged in.  If they aren't, I save the data to the session.  If they are, I save the data to the account_data table.  I built some functions to handle this:

```
from account_manager.models import account_data

def getSessionOrAccountData(request, key):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
        try:
            record = account_data.objects.get(username=username, key=key)
            return record.value
        except:
            return None
    else:
        if key in request.session.keys():
            return request.session[key]
        else:
            return None

def setSessionOrAccountData(request, key, value):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
        try:
            record = account_data.objects.get(username=username, key=key)
            record.value = value
            record.save()
        except account_data.DoesNotExist:
            record = account_data(username=username, key=key, value=str(value))
            record.save()
    else:
        request.session[key] = value

def deleteSessionOrAccountData(request, key):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
        account_data.objects.filter(username=username).filter(key=key).delete()
    else:
        del request.session[key]
```

Finally, when a user creates a new account, I want to copy any session data they might have over to the account_data table.  The following code is run right after the new user account is created:

```
# save all existing session data to new user account
for key in request.session.keys():
    record = account_data(username=request.POST['username'], 
                                  key=key, 
                                  value=str(request.session[key]))
    record.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can use the Django session, when the user is a guest user, you can save the data using the session, and when the user login, copy the data and delete the guest user.

```
def Add_To_Cart(request, pk):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user = request.user
    try:
        """ Customer Model """
        """ you can create user or guest user in Customer Model """
        authenticate_user, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        customer = authenticate_user

        """ here you can get guest user account """
        guest_user = Customer.objects.get(user=None)

        """ i have two models for my E-commerce website(OrderPost|Order) """

        """ here you can copy and create OrderPost objects from guest_user """
        guest_orderitems = OrderPost.objects.get(user=guest_user, ordered=False)
        order_item, created = OrderPost.objects.get_or_create(
            user=customer,
            item= guest_orderitems.item,
            qunatity= guest_orderitems.qunatity,
            ordered=False
        )
        guest_user.delete()
    except:
        authenticate_user, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        customer = authenticate_user 

else:
    """ When a guest user visits your website, 
        the guest user will be created without username and only with session_key """
    try:
        session_key = request.COOKIES['sessionid']
    except:
        return '0'
    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(session_key=session_key)
```